# BrowserField not showing the website.

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

This is the code i m running in my blackberry bold 9900 simulator but the BrowserField just shows the blank white screen and nothing. Is there any problem with my simulator or some setting needs to be done in it. Thanks in advance for help.

public class StartUp extends UiApplication
{

```
 public static void main(String[])
 {
       StartUp start=new StartUp();
       start.enterEventDispatcher();
 }
 public StartUp() 
 {  
    MainScreen screen = new MainScreen();
    BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField();;
    screen.add(browserField);
    pushScreen(screen);

    browserField.requestContent("http://www.google.com/news");
 }
```

}

Comment: Check your simulator has connectivity. Open the browser manually and type-in a URL.

Comment: Sorry was not well a few days..yes my simulator is opening url in its browser..

Comment: Try calling `requestContent` in a separate thread.

Answer (score 1):

Verify if you have a network connection in your simulator, see [this development guide article](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6338/Start_the_BB_MDS_Simulator_607563_11.jsp).